# Crystal Reports Sum per date from 2 different reports

Tags: crystal-reports

I have spent several hours trying to google my issue with no luck. I was wondering if anyone here would know how to do this.

I have 2 separate unrelated tables:
The first table has bank deposits(all deposits for a specific day) with the amounts example:

> 1/4/16 $10
>    1/4/16 $20
>    1/5/16 $15
>    1/5/16 $25

The second table has transactions from my billing software example:

> 1/4/16 $5
>   1/4/16 $12
>   1/4/16 $17
>   1/5/16 $22
>   1/5/16 $2
>   1/5/16 $4

I need to create a report, so that I can pull the sum for each day-

> 1/4/16 - first table sum: $30 - second table sum: $34
>   1/5/16 - first table sum: $40 - second table sum: $28

Is this possible? If so, how can I do this. I can get the sums for each table separately by using a group on the specific date field but I can not figure out how to do them both at the same time.

Comment: Can you create helper views in source database? If yes, then such calculation is best to perform at sql level, using view and create report on such view. If no, then you could create SQL expression field to sum one table over day and link it to another table.

Answer (score 0):

You can link both the tables using joins on date column and just group by date and take summary in group footer

Edit.......

I assume your last record will be duplicated so use running total.

Create a new running total

First select the field to summarize.

Second evaluate select radio button on every record

Third reset...select on change of your calculated field.

Suppose if you are summarizing amount field then

Filed to summarize: select amount

Evaluate: select for every record

Reset: on change of field amount

Comment: I have tried to do this putting both sets of data on one report but it duplicates all the data for both columns. The only options I have for Join on the transaction date -> Deposit Date is the inner join and left outer join. I have tried both of these with combinations of the "Enforce Join" to try and make it work but nothing changes the data, still duplicating.

Answer (score 0):

I you don't want to do much on database then create **two sub-reports**

- **Group data** on **date** for both reports(Suppress details and header if you don't need them).
- In both report Place `Group name` then `First/Second table sum` then `Grand total Summary`  for your amount field.
- Place both reports in front of each other and align them base line.

---

This will hopefully work for you if min date in both tables is same.
If min date is different then you can create a view or stored procedure to join data and just group it on date.

Comment: I did that for the mean time but I need to compare the data. I would like to show the difference between the 2 totals in another column and the remove if 0. I can do all that If I can figure out how to pull the data from the Group Headers and running totals fields.